# JVM argument from WAR resource deployed at tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I generated a war file which contains a keystore as a resource inside this war file and I want to deploy it at tomcat using jvm arguments in order to specify the keystore and truststore. The problem is that the relative path is always wrong according to tomcat, and I don't want to put the absolute path, since I want to deploy it at heroku and won't be able to know the absolute path? 
Here is the command line:

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=sample/truststore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=sample/keystore -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password -Djavax.net.debug=ssl -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar target/*.war
```

This sample directory is inside the /WEB-INF/classes directory inside the exploded WAR. 
PS: using the absolute path, I'm able to run the app smoothly.

How can I find out the relative path?

Comment: Try using the $CATALINA_HOME this should be set to the tomcat home directory.

Answer (score 0):

**All paths may be relative to CATALINA_BASE or CATALINA_HOME**

Refer:https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-classpath